# SQL Server : Index Seek with very high Scan Count

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, index

I have a query that joins 2 tables:

- `Documents` table, that has `DocID` as Unique Clustered Index
- `DocumentsRows` table, that has `DocID, RowID` as Unique Clustered Index

When I join those 2 tables, I usually do:

```
SELECT <somefields>
FROM Documents
INNER JOIN DocumentsRows ON Documents.DocID = DocumentsRows.DocID
WHERE <something>
```

If I run the query with `STATISTICS IO ON` and `SHOWPLAN`, I see that the engine choose Index Seek on `DocumentsRows` but the Number of Executions is equal to the Scan Count for the same table.

> Table 'DocumentsRows'. Scan count 2277, logical reads 12591, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
>   Table 'Documents'. Scan count 5, logical reads 17526, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

I know that since I'm not joining on the entire index, the seek does not retrieve only 1 value (in fact it retrieves all the rows for a specific document), then why does SQL Server choose to seek on that index instead of just scan it?

Why should an Index Seek have a so high scan count? How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you include the `WHERE` filter?

Comment: Is it relevant? This thing happens in a lot of queries that involves this kind of join, my example was just one of them. If needed I can provide the real query.

Comment: Yes, it's generally a lot easier to assess a query if you know what it is. Providing the full query & table schema(s) is best if you can.

Comment: Well, is the index seek on the clustered index or a non-clustered index? How many rows are returned? A seek is really just a range scan, and it may have high executions because the query needs to return other columns via a lookup - those are executed once per row. Also, what are you "solving"? Is the query slow, or are you just trying to get a prettier number in the scan count?

Comment: @AaronBertrand as specified on the question, the scan is on a Clustered Index.

Comment: No, it doesn't specify that in the question, you just said `choose Index Seek on DocumentsRows`...

Comment: @AaronBertrand Sorry I did not make it clear. The index I specified are the only ones on the tables. Just one clustered index per table.

Comment: Ok, so ignoring my apparently stupid question, how about the other ones? How many rows are returned? Is the query actually slow? Also, if you want help analyzing an execution plan, you should post an actual post-execution plan somewhere. Then we wouldn't have to ask all these follow-on questions.

Comment: The query is not that slow, it's just heavy. It's 2 seconds for no rows (this is the example i have)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21778788/73226

Comment: Please show the exact query, the table definitions, number of rows in both tables and the execution plan.

Comment: The question is 2 months old... The problem is already solved.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this has already been answered and would be helpful for you if you can refer to below discussion:Also, what action where clause is performing needs to be looked into:

[Why so many logical reads?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9302/why-so-many-logical-reads)

Since Logical Reads are from the data cache (memory) I would think the fact that there is a lot of reads will make little difference and it would seem that the second query is more efficient when reading a lot of data in small chunks while the first query reads the data in large chunks.

Overall, the query performance significantly can be improved using below several aspects as well:

1. Only the correct subset of rows from the * table to be retrieved, potentially reducing physical IO and locking contention
2. The CPU intensive hash functions to be eliminated
3. The memory footprint for both data and hash buckets to be reduced.

Index Seek will be used only if conditions from WHERE or ON clauses are the first in the list of columns of the Index. Also, this fields must be selective which means that the condition must filter just a little percent or rows from a table.

Also, you don't need to include column that is part of the clustered index into list of columns of a nonclustered index, because Nonclustered indexes always contain the clustered index columns if a clustered index is defined on the table.

Actually, this is very complex subject. To know more about using indexes in Sql Server you can read this article https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj835095.aspx

Comment: Well i don't think this does address my issue. My question was based on "why does an index seek do so many scans, and how can i fix it?"

Comment: @mordack550 Just edited my answer